# Regex - find specific sequence of characters, some are not letters, digits or underscore

Tags: sql, regex, impala

I am new to regex and need to search a string field in Impala for multiple matches to this exact sequence of characters: `~FC*`

since the `~` and `*` are not letters or digits, I am unsure on how to search for these in this specific order and not just for any of these single characters occuring.

This is my code so far, have tried both of these `[~FC*]` or `^~FC*$`

This is a test string, it has 2 occurrences:

```
N4*CITY*STATE*2155446*2120~FC*C*IND*30*MC*blah blah fjdgfeufh*27*0*****Y~FC*Z*IND*39*MC*jhlkfhfudfgsdkufgkusgfn*23*0*****Y~
```

Answer (score 1):

About the patterns that you tried:

- This pattern `[~FC*]` matches a single character being one of `~` `F` `C` `*`
- This pattern `^~FC*$` has anchors `^` and `$` to assert the start and the end of the string, and in between it matches `~F` followed by optional repetitions of a `C` char

If you want to find the 2 occurrences, you can use this pattern escaping the asterix:

```
~FC\\*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jnjI6n/1).

Comment: this does work in regex101.com but I had to add parentheses for this to pick up `~FC` in Impala SQL and then an extra slash allows the * to be picked up for me

`(\~FC\\*)` => `~FC*`

Comment: @e.net Great that it works with the `\\*` Do you even need the capture group as well, or will this also work with the matches only `~FC\\*`

Comment: yeah it seems I do in Impala, not in regex101 though. I tried it multiple ways without it and it never returned the correct value

Answer (score 0):

If first one does not work, please try the second one, it might work if tilde symbol is reserved in regex.

```
.*(~FC\*).* or .*(\~FC\*).*

.* - Zero or more characters
.*(~FC\*).* - Means Search for ~FC*
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working but is only grabbing 1 of the occurrences, how can I adjust it to grab all?

(btw i up voted but dont have enough rep points for it to count)

Comment: actually an extra slash allows the `*` to be picked up in impala `.*(\~FC\\*).*`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple SQL like below. This will work only on hardcoded string.

```
select (length(mycol)- length (replace(mycol,'~FC*','')))/length('~FC*') as occurance_str
```

Here is the SQL i tested ok

```
select 
(length('N4*CITY*STATE*2155446*2120~FC*C*IND*30*MC*blah blah fjdgfeufh*27*0*****Y~FC*Z*IND*39*MC*jhlkfhfudfgsdkufgkusgfn*23*0*****Y~')
- length(replace('N4*CITY*STATE*2155446*2120~FC*C*IND*30*MC*blah blah fjdgfeufh*27*0*****Y~FC*Z*IND*39*MC*jhlkfhfudfgsdkufgkusgfn*23*0*****Y~','~FC*',''))
)/length('~FC*') as occurance_str
```