# Imapala Regex - find specific sequence of characters, with delimiters between them, some are not letters, digits or underscore

Tags: sql, regex, impala

I am new to regex and need to search a string field in Impala for multiple matches to this exact sequence of characters: `~FC*` followed by 11 more `*` that could have letters/digits between (but could not, they are basically delimiters in this string field). After the 12th `*` (if you count #1 in `~FC*`) it should be immediately followed by `Y~`.

since the asterisks are not letters or digits, I am unsure on how to search for these delimiters properly.

**This is my SQL so far:**

```
select 
    regexp_extract(col_name, '(~FC\\*).*(\\*Y~)', 1) as "pattern_found"
from db.table
where id = 123456789
limit 1
```

data returned:

```
pattern_found
--------------
~FC*
```

`(~FC\\*)` in Impala SQL it returns `~FC*` which is great (got it from my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73867952/regex-find-specific-sequence-of-characters-some-are-not-letters-digits-or-un))

Been trying this `(~FC\\*).*(\\*Y~)` which obviously isnt counting the number of asterisks but its is also not picking the Y up.

This is a test string, it has 2 occurrences:

```
N4*CITY*STATE*2155446*2120~FC*C*IND*30*MC*blah blah fjdgfeufh*27*0*****Y~FC*Z*IND*39*MC*jhlkfhfudfgsdkufgkusgfn*23*0*****Y~
```

results should be these 2, which has an overlapping `~` between them. but will settle for at least the first being found if both cannot.

`~FC*C*IND*30*MC*blah blah fjdgfeufh*27*0*****Y~`
`~FC*Z*IND*39*MC*jhlkfhfudfgsdkufgkusgfn*23*0*****Y~`

Answer (score 0):

figured out a solution but happy to learn of a better way to accomplish this

This is what worked in Impala SQL, needed parentheses and double escape backslashes for allllll the asterisks:

```
(~FC\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*Y)
```

Full SQL:

```
select 
    regexp_extract(col_name, '(~FC\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*[^\\*]*\\*Y)', 1) as "pattern_found"
from db.table
where id = 123456789
limit 1
```

and here is the [RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/PSySfR/1) without the additional syntax needed for Impala SQL